# Is there no way to parallelize calls to an executable in Windows

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I've got a list of files for each of which I'm calling `sox`. Because it takes a while I thought I'd speed the process up by parallelizing it, each call to `sox` is independent of each other so I thought it'd be a simple thing.

But it seems you cannot call the same executable from a different process, as that leads to an `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.` error.
I'm guessing that is the cause because there's no other file I'm using across different processes. And yet I'm quite surprised by this, why would RO access not be possible? And does that really mean there's absolutely no way for me to speed my program up?

Comment: I have no idea what you are saying.

Comment: @Nimitz14 you can _of course_ call a same program from different (parallel) processes - assuming this program has not be written in a way that prevent it that is (either by itself or because the way you invoked it).  FWIW you might just have a totally unrelated app actually blocking access to one of the file passed to sox...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers  +1 *All hostilities are racism, including anti-racism.65 million people only care about 6 million?  Who is racist ?

Comment: The error message is for `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION`. Windows requires cooperative access to files. The system keeps a count of the number of times a file has been opened; the number of opens that have been granted read, write, or delete (R-W-D) access; and the number of opens that have shared R-W-D access. This determines whether it can grant R-W-D access to a subsequent request to open the file. Despite the wording of the error message, this error isn't necessarily due to "another process".

Comment: That's interesting, but doesn't actually give me any actionable information.

Comment: For example: Can I change the number of opens, would that idea be bad, I'm accessing sox from different processes why wouldnt it be from another process?

Comment: Your question doesn't provide actionable information. You need to put more work into the question. Reduce the problem down to a minimal, complete example. A minimal example is as small and self-contained as possible.

Comment: Every time a file is opened, the system is passed the desired access and whether read, write, and delete access should be shared. It doesn't matter what process a subsequent open is in. For example, if you open without read sharing, then a subsequent open will fail if it requests read access, even from the current process. To get around this, you can do duplicate handles or have a child process inherit handles and pass the inherited handle values on the command line or an environment variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error. I had at the end of my sox command `2> $nul` to suppress the output. That was of course causing issues. :D